# How do you ask "Will you see your child next Sunday" in Chinese using verb not verb structure?

Tags: translation, usage, negation, yes-no-questions

What will be the difference between 你下个星期天**会不会**见你的孩子 and 你下个星期天会**见不见**你的孩子 ?

I am learning these sentences on Duolingo :) and was given the meaning of 你下个星期天会不会见你的孩子 as *"Will you see your child next Sunday?"*.

It would be great if anyone can explain how different would the other sentence (你下个星期天会见不见你的孩子) mean be from the first one.

And can these both sentences be equally written as 你下个星期天会见你的孩子**吗**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the main issue is covered in a [Yoyo Chinese YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yu7GPWS2FKE) (starting around 1:20); they use the two-verb example:

> 你**会**说中文。
>   你**会不会**说中文?

The Yoyo Chinese video describes this as "focusing on the main verb --> usually the first verb".  So...

> *Correct*: 你下个星期天**会不会见**你的孩子？
>   *Incorrect*: 你下个星期天**会见不见**你的孩子？

And...

> *Correct*: 你下个星期天会见你的孩子吗?

Additional complications arise because [会见](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BC%9A%E8%A7%81) and [不见](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%8D%E8%A7%81) are also verbs in their own right (as in [jack chiou's answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/38736/8099)).

Answer (score 2):

the second has two verb. 會見and 不見(or maybe the sentence just ignore the conjunction.this is not formal)。
Here is correct grammar

```
你下个星期天见不见你的孩子
```

just take 会 away and the sentence will be perfect and have the same meaning as the former sentence.
or add conjunction

```
你下个星期天见或是不见你的孩子
```

And can these both sentences be equally written as 你下个星期天会见你的孩子吗?**yes**